# How to restart a slide show in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

How do I stop and restart a slide show created using JQuery?

```
$('#left_actual').cycle('stop'); //slide show 1
$('#right_col').cycle('stop'); //slide show 2
$('#left_actual').cycle({ fx: 'all',
                       timeout: 6010,
                       startingSlide:slide_no // changing slide number
});

$('#right_col').cycle({ fx:'scrollRight',
                       timeout: 6000,
                       startingSlide:slide_no, // changing slide number
                       before:button_chg
});
```

Comment: which jQuery plugin? any associated code? please don't ask such incomplete questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The JQuery Cycle Plugin works great**

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

See the [tutorials](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/more.html?v2.23)

Stop by calling:

```
$('#cycleElementId').cycle('pause');
```

Restart by calling:

```
$('#cycleElementId').cycle(0);
```

Comment: while using that some images were gone any other reason

Comment: @Arun is it a browser / css issue? try different browsers & turning off CSS to see if you can reproduce it.  Any chance you have an example we can see?

Comment: Runs fine for me, looks like you just have tabs, try adding more description to what you're trying to do and the problem you're having to the question.

Comment: i want to change slide no by clicking tab. But Some images are 

missing while selecting tab but not all times, it happens after an 

uncertain period.